# Getting frame width from spritesheet

Tags: algorithm, graphics, visualization, sprite-sheet

For awhile I tried to create some simple games based on MonoGame, but I faced a problem.

I found some spritesheets in [spritedatabase](http://spritedatabase.net), but some of the images on a current sheet were with different width /[Example](http://spritedatabase.net/file/4555)/. I mean that on the third row /from top to the bottom/, where running images are located, are with different width than these on the fourth one.

The first thing that pop - up in my head was to copy - paste and resize all the images, but I am 100% sure there is a more delicate way to do this.

So the question is: *How to get the size of current frame before I draw it? Should I use some image recognition algorithm or not?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the sprite sheet you provided lacks extra information that would enable you to paste it without complications. First of all you should need to know the origin for each frame, and secondly its dimensions. Dimensions in sprite sheets may vary however in such case only the right origin will guarantee that sprite is always positioned correctly. Note that sprite sheets in such databases (usually ripped with disregard to copyright) are often packed manually in Photoshop or other similar software. This unfortunately requires some serious effort to process them. So to use them you should extract all the frames, place them in layers and make sure that logical origin is in the same place (for side-scroller and bipedal characters it could be point between feet).

Anyway, I would extract each sprite manually. You could also use segment_image [script](http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11705) with ImageMagick. But probalbly manual work will be of same or even less effort.

Afterwards I would enlarge canvas all the extacted frames to largest frame dimensions. Pack this into spritesheet, import to [Piskel](http://piskelapp.com/) and reposition each frame to have proper origin. The final tool is frankly irrelevant as you could also use Flash or Photoshop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also though that this would be the way, but is always better if you ask /if you can't find the information by your own/.